# How do i open a file larger than available memory in visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, large-files

In my pre-windows days, i recall using a hex editor that only loaded in the part of the file i was working on. I need to load a file that is larger than available memory into visual studio to search for a string ( it's a 28GB MySQL dump file and i only have 8GB of RAM ). Is this possible in visual studio 2019 ? Windows 10 search finds nothing - it seems to ignore large files.

Comment: If you find the string what is your next move? Do you plan to edit the huge file?

Comment: No need to edit. I am looking for missing tables that i know were there during the backup, but for some reason don't get restored. If i find the string, it proves there is a problem with the restore. If i don't find the string, it proves there is a problem creating the backup.

Comment: You should use some other file viewer instead of Visual Studio. When dealing with such huge files we don't plan on editing them, just viewing. [Glogg](https://glogg.bonnefon.org/) is meant for viewing log files of arbitrary size, but it can view any other text file as well. Regex is supported.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to open this in VisualStudio
If you only need to search for string you do not need to open the file at all you can use comand prompt:

```
findstr /C:"yourSearchString" "C:\path\to\your\file.sql"
```

if you want to open the file in some editor I know that [EmEditor][1] is capable

Also you can use [WSL][2] to split the fine into smaller sections:

```
split -b 1G "your_large_file.sql" "part_"
```

as @
user20716902
mentioned it would be advised to use

```
strings "C:\path\to\your\file.sql" | find "yourSearchString"
```

because findstr could get line is too long error because the format of the file
[1]: https://www.emeditor.com
[2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/

Comment: I'm not sure of the format of a MySQL Dump file, but if it's binary you will likely run into issues trying to use findstr, as it parses lines using LF. You might just get many "Line is too long" errors.

Comment: @user20716902 what would be the way tho? not that experienced with the command line

Comment: You could use the following command `strings "C:\path\to\your\file.sql" | find "yourSearchString"`

Comment: while the search string is almost certainly in a short line ( less than 2048 characters ), findstr returns lots of 'FINDSTR: Line XXXX is too long.' warnings which make it difficult to see where the search string 'CREATE TABLE `abc` might occur. the pipe commands don't seem to work with findstr.